# How to untar a .img file?

Tags: linux, image, tar

I was in needed of backing up a .img file, basically what I had to do was to compress the file and copy it to another location. On the begining this file was a +800GB file, so I ran this command:

```
tar -cvf file.img file.tar
```

Of course that I didn't see the problem of the command till this was promped

> tar: fle.tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
>   tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Now I ran the command properly after that error

```
tar -cvf file.tar file.img
```

And this time succeeded... The problem came when I realized the original +800GB file was now a 12KB file.

I don't know If I damaged the file or if it was compressed, If so, how do I get back the original size of the file?

I am using a linux SLES 11

Comment: you can untar with: `tar -xvf file.tar`, then check the file.img size..

Comment: Just did it and didn't work

Comment: and what is the output?

Comment: "tar: slesapps.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now"

Comment: slesapps.tar?? how did this come from?

Comment: that's the name of the file

Comment: you might not have permission in the current directory, try as root.

Comment: currently I am root user and the permission of the file are 644 rw-r--r--

Comment: I do not know what you are using tar version, but check this link about limitation: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_68.html  (so try to archive a 'normal size' file first...)

Comment: If this is only one file, and you are trying to compress it: try using bzip2 or bunzip2 directly (or someting else, like xz): e.g. $ bzip2 file.img

Comment: Thank you guys... I am glad you share some time trying to help me out... the file was never recovered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ran

```
tar -cvf file.img file.tar
```

you overwrote file.img, creating a tar file with no contents, even though the `tar` commmand appeared to fail.  So when you swapped the parameters around, your large image file was gone.  Sorry but I think you've lost the file.

Comment: Thanks tho, I hoped there was a way to restore the file... there goes one day of work... shame on me

Answer (score 0):

"man tar" will help you
-c = create new tar file
-x = extract tar file
and compression options are -z -Z -j (-z -Z -y on BSD & MAC)